# By learning from incomplete episodes, does David Silver mean learning of $V(s)$ even when the episode is not completed?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods

I came across the $TD(0)$  algorithm from Sutton and Barto:
[image]

Clearly, the only difference of TD methods with the MC methods is that TD method is not waiting till the end of the episode to update the $V(s)$ or $Q(s,a)$, but according to David Silver's lecture (Lecture 4- ~34:00),

[image]

The $TD(0)$ algorithm learns from incomplete episodes, but in the earlier algorithm we can see that the loop repeats until $s$ is terminal which mean completion of episode.

So, by learning from incomplete episodes, does David Silver mean learning of $V(s)$ even when the episode is not completed? Or did I interpret the algorithm wrong? If so, what is the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The $TD(0)$ algorithm learns from incomplete episodes, but in the earlier algorithm we can see that the loop repeats until $s$ is terminal which mean completion of episode.

In the pseudocode, you have two loops: one for each episode and one (nested) for each step of the episode. The *until $S$ is terminal* means that you perform the updates until you end the episode (that is, you end up in a terminal state, e.g. checkmate in the game of chess). *For each step of the episode*, you perform the TD(0) update.

Apparently, you're confusing two things: the fact that each episode ends in a terminal state and the fact that TD learns from incomplete information. Each episode ends in a terminal state (otherwise it would not be called an episode), but this does not mean that it collects a full rollout before updating $V$. In fact, at each step of the episode, it updates $V$.

The information in the David Slider's slide is consistent with the pseudocode. TD learns from experience because it uses the given policy $\pi$ to behave.

> So, by learning from incomplete episodes, does David Silver mean learning of $V(s)$ even when the episode is not completed?

Yes, essentially, you're updating the value function during each step of each episode.